# Collecting metrics for average time taken by flink flatmap function

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus, metrics

I have implemented a flink flatmap function and I want to collect metrics for average time for this function which I plan to monitor via prometheus.

What would be good approach for it? I have added a gauge to the method(extending Gauge interface from flink API).

```
public class SimpleGauge<T> implements Gauge<T> {

    private T mValue;

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void setValue(T value){
        mValue = value;
    }
}
```

And I call setValue from flatmap function:

```
float endTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000F;
this.gauge.setValue(endTime);
```

Would it work?

Comment: This was also asked and answered on the mailing list. See http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Metrics-for-average-time-taken-by-flatMap-function-td40549.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it will work or not depends on how do You create the `Gauge`. You should probably switch to `RichFlatMapFunction` if You are using the plain `FlatMapFunction` and then initialize and register Your gauge `getRuntimeContext`.

Also, You may want to read a little bit on metric types because `Histogram` seems to be a better idea than Gauge in this case, as measuring the average latency isn't generally the best idea in most of the cases.

Comment: Yes, historgram seems to be  better option here.

Comment: Flink Histogram doesnt offer sum metrics, only count metrics.